# Problems with control flow structures using strings

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, controls

Below is method that asks for a medium that is either air, water, or steel. If what is entered isn't one of these, the programs ends. If it is a valid medium, it asks for a distance it will travel and calculates the time through each medium. The problem I am having is getting to the else statement.

Yes, this is a homework question. No, I'm not looking for the solution, just why the else and switches aren't being evaluated. I have already checked, and my jdk is version 7. Thanks in advance.

```
package speedofsound;
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class SpeedOfSound {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String medium;
    int distance, time;

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter one of the following: air, water, or steel: ");
    medium = read.next();

    if (!medium.equals("air")|| !medium.equals("steel")|| !medium.equals("water")){
        System.out.print("Sorry, you must enter air, water, or steel.");
    }
    else {
    System.out.print("Enter the distance the sound wave will travel: ");
    distance = read.nextInt();
    switch(medium){
        case "air":
            time = distance/1100;
            System.out.println("It will take "+time+ "seconds.");
            break;
        case "water":
            time = distance/4900;
            System.out.println("It will take "+time+ "seconds.");
            break;
        case "steel":
            time = distance/16400;
            System.out.println("It will take "+time+ "seconds.");
            break;

    }

    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: if this is homework, you should learn something from it. My suggestion: learn how to debug this small program in Eclipse and use the debugger to step it through and display the variables while doing this. You will have to learn this anyway, so why not do it today ? ;-)

Comment: It is nor your task to improve the program ? If it is: I have some suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition:

```
 if (!medium.equals("air") || !medium.equals("steel") || !medium.equals("water"))
```

is incorrect. Replace the `||` with `&&`.

It might be a bit confusing when you think about it literally but `medium` can **only** be equal to one value so you want to make sure that:

(`medium` == x **OR** `medium` == y **OR** `medium` == z)

the opposite will be:

(`medium` != x **AND** `medium` != y **AND** `medium` != z)

where in this case you want to print the error message.

Comment: well, logical operations might be confusing even with a debugger;)

Answer (score 0):

Condition Expression is wrong

use this

```
 if (!medium.equals("air") && !medium.equals("steel") && !medium.equals("water"))
```

instead of

```
 if (!medium.equals("air")|| !medium.equals("steel")|| !medium.equals("water"))
```